# Deploy Rails 5 App Using Bitbucket & Digital Ocean & Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, capistrano, digital-ocean

I am having problems with deploying a rails app onto Digital Ocean. The app uses Rails 5, ruby 2.4.0, capistrano, and passenger. I am trying to connect a private repository in bitbucket to digital ocean via SSH, which maybe my problem.

Here is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, 'APP_NAME'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/APP_NAME.git'

set :user, "deploy"
set "stages", %w(production staging)
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my deploy/production.rb file:

```
role :app, %w{deploy@ADDRESS}
role :web, %w{deploy@ADDRESS}
role :db, %w{deploy@ADDRESS}, :primary => true
set :branch, "master"
set :rails_env, "staging"
set :deploy_to, "var/www/APP_NAME_production"
```

I have been following the this [tutorial on how to setup a rails app on digital ocean](https://rubythursday.com/episodes/ruby-snack-15-deploy-to-digital-ocean-part-4).

I can complete a cap staging deploy:check but get the following error when I run a cap staging deploy:

```
fatal: destination path 'var/www/APP_NAME/repo' already exists and is not an empty directory.
...
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED:
Gems -

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
ruby '2.4.0'
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
 ...
  gem 'capistrano', '~>3.4.0'
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~>1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger' 
end
```

Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/ssh_doctor'
# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please also post your Capfile and Rails and Capistrano gem versions. Thanks!

Comment: Does this issue apply to you? https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1831

Comment: @mwahnish I added them. Any ideas?

Comment: @MattBrictson Do I need to use a newer version of capistrano because I am using Rails 5?

Comment: I updated capistrano to 3.7.2 and still get the same error. The command that fails is the git clone --mirror. It says fatal: destination path '' already exists and is not an empty directory. Also, I have tried to remove the directory and clear it but get my server says the folder does not exist.

Comment: You could also try updating capistrano-rails.  It's up to 1.2.2

Comment: I updated capistrano-rails, but it did not solve the problem. Could it be with my SSH?

Comment: You probably meant to write `set :deploy_to, "/var/www/APP_NAME_production"` (yours is missing the leading slash).

Comment: @MattBrictson - you are right. Thank you so much.